# How to search and identify a float value in a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which has string and float values like below:

```
"c1","c2","c3"
"A","1.3334343434","1"
"B","2","6.434343443434"
"D","3.434344343443","P"
"B","2.446647884844","Z"
"A","2","1.98984934394943"
```

I need to identify only float in this file and round it off up to 2 decimal places.
If i am using this as pandas data frame it gives an error.
Not sure how to identify a float value to do the round() operation. 
Looking for suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: what is the error when you try to use pandas?

Comment: The main reason for this is, that your column contains multiple types of values. You might have an issue if you are working on it as a dataframe, because dataframes deal over a whole column. But I guess you can use where. Let me give it a try.

Comment: What do you want to do with `P` and `Z` in your `c3` column? You wan't to remove them?

Comment: Is there a way to identify the columns which has only float values from the csv file ? like c2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is by using a simple custom function, apply and inside that a try and catch.

```
data=pd.read_csv('newdata.csv')

print(data)
```

The data is as provided:

```
  c1        c2                c3
0  A  1.333434                 1
1  B  2.000000    6.434343443434
2  D  3.434344                 P
3  B  2.446648                 Z
4  A  2.000000  1.98984934394943
```

Now we create a custom function which takes column by column from a dataframe and rounds of any float to 2 decimal places:

```
def change(m):
    k=[]

    for x in m:
        try:
            k.append(round(float(x),2))

        except:
            k.append(x)
    return k


data.apply(lambda x: change(x))
```

And the output is:

```
    c1   c2      c3
0   A   1.33    1
1   B   2.00    6.43
2   D   3.43    P
3   B   2.45    Z
4   A   2.00    1.99
```

What the function does is, inside the try statement it tries to convert anything into a float, if possible, it rounds it off and sends it back, and if there's an error, it returns back the original value(whether string or anything else).

The solution suggested by the other user is pretty good too. So, go for those if that helps you better.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, Let me check this.

Answer (score 2):

For your `c2` column we can use [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html#pandas.Series.round) since it's already in `float` type.

And for the `c3` column we look for we can match all decimal numbers and [`slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) them off after the 4th character, since they are still `strings`

```
# Print initial df
  c1        c2                c3
0  A  1.333434                 1
1  B  2.000000    6.434343443434
2  D  3.434344                 P
3  B  2.446648                 Z
4  A  2.000000  1.98984934394943
```

---

```
df['c2'] = df['c2'].round(2)
df['c3'] = np.where(df['c3'].str.match('\d\.\d+'), df['c3'].str.slice(stop=4), df['c3'])

  c1    c2    c3
0  A  1.33     1
1  B  2.00  6.43
2  D  3.43     P
3  B  2.45     Z
4  A  2.00  1.98
```

---

If you want to have column `c3` in float type as well, you have to drop the rows with `P` and `Z`:

```
df['c3'] = np.where(df['c3'].str.match('\d\.\d+|\d+'), 
                    df['c3'], 
                    np.NaN).astype(float).round(2)

  c1    c2    c3
0  A  1.33  1.00
1  B  2.00  6.43
2  D  3.43   NaN
3  B  2.45   NaN
4  A  2.00  1.99
```

**Edit** after OP comment about *all* columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = np.where(df[col].str.match('\d\.\d+|\d+'), 
                       df[col], 
                       np.NaN).astype(float).round(2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, Is it possible to identify every element from each column and if that element is float, then round it off ?